# Django 1.4 model admin url rewrite for admin models "tree like" structure

Tags: python, django, url, admin

I searched all over and did not find any answer to this. 
I'm using Django 1.4 and my problem is this:
I'm trying to implement in contrib admin a "tree like" models structure.

Let's say we have model A and model B that is a child of model A,
in admin change_list grid of A when I click on an item I should redirect to model B change_list view and filter it with children of A.

In previous version of Django I just rewrote the child models admin urls and added (?(\d+)).

Ex: add url ^(.+)/ was changed to ^(?< parent_id >(\d+))/(.+)/ so in change view I retrieved  the parent object and used it for all required filtering and also sent it in context to be displayed in breadcrumbs.

It worked because in all admin templates then we had relative links for breadcrumbs, add, delete, history,..., so for example the Cancel button in confirm delete page had href='../../' and clicking on it would have taken me from app/model/parent_id/obj_id/delete to app/model/parent_id

Due to the changes in 1.4 where all template links are generated with reverse url I obviously get errors with NoReverseMatch. A temporary fix was to pass the parent id in session so that I can have it in all child admin pages (I don't think that this is a good way to go for many reasons).

Bottom line I'm trying to rewrite the admin urls in a way that won't interfere with current templates so that I can send the parent id in the url (sending it in the query string is also not an option)
Is there anyone out there that did something similar?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, only the more straightforward/robust customizations to Django's admin are a good idea. If you do something like what you are describing, you are risking incompatibility with new versions (as you have already experienced).

Comment: What you ask is not really possible or doable in a reliable fashion - you would have to monkeypatch django's url dispatcher (cause the "parent part" of the url is dynamic but the admin is to be mounted on a static path).